# Is $p$ is equivalent to the discrete metric ? Are they topologically equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

let $X$  be  a  nonempty set . Define  a map  on  $X \times X$  by

$$p(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0,& \text{if }x=y \\ 2,& \text{if } x \neq y \end{cases}$$

Is  $p$ is equivalent  to the  discrete metric?  Are  they topologically  equivalent?

My attempt:  I  think  $p$  will be  equivalent  to the  discrete metric because  both  metric have  same format  define on non- empty set    but I'm not  sure about topologically equivalent

any hints/solution

thanks u

Comment: It would be helpful if you added context to your question.  How, precisely, do you define the discrete metric?  What does it mean for two metrics to be topologically equivalent?  Your conclusion is correct (presuming that you are using standard definitions), but your argument is unconvincing.  A rigorous argument would refer to specific definitions or theorems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are topologically equivalent because they have the same collection of open sets (namely *all* subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are open in this metric, as in the discrete metric).